# What conditions of birational map does the numerically equivalence preserve?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Let $f:X\dashrightarrow Y$ be a birational map between normal varieties. 
What conditions of birational map  does the numerically equivalence preserve?
In other words, I want to know the conditions of $f$ satisfying the following property. If we let $D$ and $D'$ be divsors on $X$ such that $D$ is numerically equivalent to $D'$, then $f_*D$ and $f_*D'$ are numerical equivalence.

Comment: What do you mean by $f_*$ when $f$ is a rational map? If you mean the strict transform (i.e. the closure of the image of $D \cap U$, where $U$ is a big open set where $f$ is defined), then there is little hope. Essentially, you need $D$ and $D'$ to be contained in $U$. As a counterexample, imagine $D$ and $D'$ are lines in the plane, and let $f$ be the inverse of the blow-up at a point that is in $D$ but not in $D'$. On the other hand, in case $f_*$ means $p_* \circ q^*$, where $p$ and $q$ are resolutions of indeterminacies of $f$ and its inverse, then the numerical equivalence is preserved.